# SQL Injection Method

Tags: sql, sql-injection

The Injection Procedures are :

```
SELECT UserId, Name, Password FROM Users WHERE UserId = 105 or 1=1;
```

But, My Question Is how the injection query is working in the sql?

Comment: When adding `or 1=1` the `WHERE` statement becomes irrelevant, and always return true, and thus, the query is always executed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Found 'OR 1=1/\* sql injection in my newsletter database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867266/found-or-1-1-sql-injection-in-my-newsletter-database)

Answer (score 1):

its when you have your query as string in your code, something like this

```
Query = "SELECT UserId, Name, Password FROM Users WHERE UserId = '" + sUserID + "'"
```

So you pass sUserID = "ABC' OR 1=1;"

this will be translated like

```
SELECT UserId, Name, Password FROM Users WHERE UserId = 'ABC' OR 1=1
```

Comment: @IsmayilS happy to hear that i helped :) please mark it as an answer if it did

Answer (score 1):

Since the condition `1=1` is always `true`, adding it at the end of a `WHERE` statement renders it irrelevant, and always `true`, as if the `WHERE` statement does not exist at all. Thus, the query is always executed, regardless of any other conditions added to the `WHERE` statement.

In the example you provided, If you allow your users to write down their own `userID`, they can write `105 or 1=1` in the input fields or in a website's URL address, and since `or 1=1` makes `UserId=105` useless, and the query will always select the data, hence the SQL injection.