# Sql Injection Method Clarification

Tags: mysql, sql-server

From this sql Query,

```
 select Id, Name from Student1 
 where Id = 1;
```

The Table records will appear only one data

```
 1  Ramu S
```

But, This query when execute,

```
 SELECT Id, Name FROM Student1 WHERE Id = '' OR 1=1
```

it shows all the records of the table. So, how the query functions?

Comment: the OR 1=1 is always true .. so select all the rows ..

Comment: The condition `1=1` is always true.  Hence _injecting_ the string `OR 1=1` to the end of the query causes the whole table to be returned.

Comment: Why are you asking the same question again 2h later? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44878026/sql-injection-method

Answer (score 0):

You have to run query as:

SELECT Id, Name FROM Student1 WHERE Id = ' ' OR Id='1';

In the query u are executing :
 SELECT Id, Name FROM Student1 WHERE Id = '' OR 1=1;

you are actually asking for all the ID, Name from Student1 where condition (ID = ' ') is true or 1=1 is true. As 1 is always equals to 1 you will get all the values in the table

Answer (score 0):

You can leave the ‘1 = 1’ without any problem as no sensible query-optimizer will evaluate it at runtime. It is a constant (TRUE) and when it is on its own or is followed by ‘AND’ it will be ignored [ TRUE AND Expr == Expr] or when it is followed by ‘OR’ the expression following the ‘OR’ will be ignored [TRUE OR Expr == TRUE).
 I often use this construct when i construct a WHERE-clause where each part starts off with ‘AND …’. If no part applies, the (1=1) is still there.

Comment: I would never keep that '1=1' because when you are using an OR like in the OP's example it means that whatever value he does in 'where id = ''' will be ignored and the query will always return all records.

Comment: That's true in case of using OR. But in case of AND, I often use this construct especially if the list of conditions is not known at compile time and is instead built at run time, you don't have to worry about whether you have one or more than one condition, you can generate your query like: WHERE 1=1 AND conditions... \

Comment: Yes but the OP's question is specific about OR

Comment: And it would be better to use parameters when the conditions are not know at compile time, something like 'where @@ID is not null AND ID = @@ID' (I use 2 @@ because I cannot type only one in a comment)

Comment: Agree on using the parameterized approach, that's the more better way.

Answer (score 0):

if you build a query like this :

```
string sql = 'select id, name from student1 where id = ' + textEdit1.Text
```

then anyone can type 1 or 1=1 in textEdit1 which will result in

```
select id, name from student1 where id = 1 or 1=1
```

If you do it with parameter like this :

```
string sql = 'select id, name from student1 where id = @id'
using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sql)
{
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", textEdit1.text)
    etc...
}
```

then the value will be invalid if the user types '1 or 1=1' because the compiler will do checks for you and discover that this value does not fits in that field.
It's actually more complicated I guess but that is the simplest explanation for what is going on.

About how the query works

Because you use an OR it means that only one of both expression has to be true.
So either `id = '' has to be true` OR `1=1 has to be true`.

And  since 1 is always 1 this condition will always return true and therefore all records in your table will be returned.
In this case the first condition `id = ''` is ignored because the second condition `1=1` is true.

That would be different if you would use an AND in stead of an OR.
In that case both conditions need to be true and `id = '' AND 1=1` will only return records where the is equals ''
In this case the second condition is ignored because it is always true.